# XMLHTTPRequest Level 2 and CORS server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

Can anyone tell me if there are web sites that offer some services (news, time, weather etc.) that understand CORS requests so I can implement a mashup with a Javascript application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this. Not much but it's a start.

**edit:** The following Wikipedia page has been deleted but it has some history.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Web_services_allowing_access_from_any_origin

imwilsonxu has provided a better alternative.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#Services

Comment: Good find! I'll add another one when it goes into production sometime Q1

Comment: Since the wiki link was broken, I found this: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#Services